# Is there a way to get the same first or second element tuple in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've struggled with this question for a long time, and I didn't find much useful information online. I tried to use for loop, but I can use it like c++ with an index like `i+2` to get that element. If I have a list like `[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)]`. There are several tuples on the list. 4 appear three times as the first element of tuples. And 2 appear three times as the second element of tuples. How can I get `(4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)` and `[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)`out from the list because they have the same element of the tuple?

Comment: Do you already know which ones you need ("first element in is 4") or do you have to find that out as well ("group of at least n tuples where the first/last element is equal")?

Comment: That's unclear, I read that 5 times and I still don't get it sorry, could you explain differently "the same first or second element of tuple out" ? why keep `(2, 3), (3, 5)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,  I need to check the value of the same position of tuple. I need to check the first element to find the match, and the second element to find the match.

Comment: How would you write it in C…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` here

```py
lst = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)]

same_first = 4

new_lst = list(filter(lambda e:e[0]==same_first,lst))
print(new_lst)
```

Or Make a function.

```py
lst = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)]

def same(lst,same_number,choice):
    return list(filter(lambda e:e[choice]==same_number,lst))
    
# change choice to 0 for first and 1 for second 
print(same(lst=lst,same_number=2,choice=1)) # [(4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7)]

print(same(lst=lst,same_number=2,choice=1)) # [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, it's really helpful.